# Improve rise-time of NPN current mirror

Tags: analog, rise-time, current-mirror

I'm looking for a way to improve the rise-time of a current mirror.

My problem is as follows: I want to interface with an obscure single wire protocol.

I'm starting with a digital signal that has a high level that can be anything between 1.8 to 5V (shown in the graphic as DigIn). I need to load this signal based on a different digital signal with a fixed voltage (I'm generating this signal). This signal is shown as ModulateIn in the graphic.

The current that I draw from the DigIn signal should be independent of the signalling level of DigIn. Around 1mA, but there is some wiggle-room.

To do so I load the DigIn signal using a standard current mirror as shown below:

[image: Circuit showing my current mirror]

The circuit works as it should except for one thing: I'm not happy with the rise-time. If ModulateIn goes high, it takes a while until the transistors start to conduct. This can be seen in a small delay in the current drawn from DigIn.

I'm dealing with frequencies of roughly 4Mhz here, that's why I picked fast RF transistors.

Question: How can I improve the response-time of the current mirror? I tried speed-up techniques from transistor switching applications like adding a speed-up capacitor parallel to the base resistor, but that does not work.

Any idea how to improve the rise-time except for picking even faster transistors?

Comment: I had to read it around 10 times to understand it. Basically, when ModulatieIn goes high, you need to turn on a current sink that draws approximately 1mA from DigIn, which might be anywhere from 1.8 to 5V. Is that it? Is there another voltage available that we can draw quiescent current from all the time? And by the way, there is no need for two transistors. You can do this pretty nicely using 1 transistor, although I am not sure the switch time will improve.

Comment: When you say you tried a cap in parallel with the base resistor, you mean you put a cap in parallel with R3 of the above schematic?

Comment: Instead of showing how you think you can implement something why don't you simply state what you want to happen re inputs and outputs?

Comment: How fast does it need to be?

Comment: Are you allowed to change ModulateIn to some other voltage? Say 1V or 1.2V?

Comment: @mkeith V(ModulateIn) comes from a comparator with complementary output. Each output swings between ~0.2V and 3V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use faster transistors and add a bit of bias you can reduce the delay significantly. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fygYqg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has simulated rise time of < 4ns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll try a simulation tonight. Rise-time less than 4ns would be great.

Comment: This is roughly why I initially asked whether there was a power rail available. To help bias the transistor ahead of time to reduce switching speed.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck tip: reduce the maximum step size in SPICE to get a more accurate simulation of rapid rise times. (in this case, maybe 0.1ns or less).

Comment: @mkeith there are separate power-rails at -4.5V, +5V and and +8.5V available.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: mkeith pointed out a flaw in my design. The reduced beta could be a problem with Q4 in saturation. I'll leave this here because it has some other good information, but the circuit itself will not work because when Vmod is high, DigIn will be driven backwards by Q4 which is likely highly undesirable.

---

Current mirror's don't work very accurately with discrete components because there's high levels of transistor mis-match so I doubt current mirrors are a good idea here. Other issues with your circuit include the high resistance of R3 slowing down how fast current may be injected into Q2 and Q1. The configuration you have is forcing your current value (1mA) to be directly correlated to the switching speed. If you raised the current, you would switch faster, but you've specified that the current needs to remain at about 1mA. That means we've got to somehow decouple these two design parameters.

Here's one attempt at resolving the issues you speak of.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxJWfU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q3 is in common-collector (emitter-follower) configuration so there's no miller effect so it's a fast switch.

Q1 and Q4 are in a cascode configuration which reduces the gain of Q1 reducing miller effect and thereby increasing the frequency response of it. Q4 is doing nothing more than pinning Q1's collector voltage to ~2.3 at a maximum by the typical 0.7V Vbe threshold voltage of a bjt. Q1 has two purposes, with it's base at ~2.3V when Vmod is high, the emitter will be at approximately 1.6V. 1.6V/1.6kohms gives you the 1mA current you're after. At the same time, this is the switching transistor. When Vmod goes low, the base of Q1 goes low and prevents any current flowing from Dig_Sig down to ground.

Lastly, R2 should be set to any value of your choosing. The higher the resistance, the slower response the circuit will have. The lower the resistance, the more quiescent current you'll be wasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll first have to understand it fully before I can accept it.

Comment: @horta, Did you check to make sure the collector current of Q4 is around 1mA over the full range of operating voltage? Won't Q4 be in heavy saturation, and thus operating with greatly reduced beta? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Cascode configuration is often a useful trick to defeat Miller capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a regulated voltage rail availble, there is a simple way to construct a single-transistor current sink which maintains a fairly constant current across a fairly wide range of VCC. By itself, I don't think this circuit will help you, but I will present it anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVDgm3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, it is an emitter follower. By putting 0.5V across R3, it draws around 1mA from collector regardless of the voltage at DigIn. However, I don't think this will be a fast switcher either.

There is a temperature coefficient issue, but depending on the accuracy needed, it may work well enough.

Comment: Good catch on my circuit. That brings up a related issue. If DigIn is 1.8V, I'll actually have reverse conduction which would prevent DigIn from ever dropping low. I'm too used to designing with mosfets which don't have that problem. I'll delete my answer. Thanks for spotting the error!

Comment: You don't have to delete it. Maybe just add a note? I think it is a very useful answer, and discrete transistor design is a tricky business.